# What is the best way to store multiple entries / arrays on MYSQL table

Tags: php, mysql

I´m coding a PHP form-based medical record, with multiple users and fully customizable options. Each user will be able, for example, to create multiple template texts, each appointment having multiple prescriptions, exams, and so on...

The question is: what is the best way of storing these data and arrays into a MYSQL table, memory and CPU usage wise?

Right now, I´m storing these data into json-formatted text in individual columns (like "options", "templates", "prescription"), but it seems a little harsh to code/decode and reformat all these entries each time they are called.

The second option, would be creating a new line for each text, which would be easier to store and retrieve, but could potentially create huge tables.

The website works perfectly with option 1, so I´m being a little perfectionist here, but will appreciate your opinion.

Comment: You should normalise the data, create new tables for each set of information.  JSON might seem nice and easy, but hides the data and doesn't help in creating a flexible and modern system (IMHO)

Comment: Best way is to analyze your data and create normalized tables, with proper indexing etc. Storing arrays isn't a good option esp when we may need to search the tables later on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, just to perhaps help slightly here.
Say I've got a set of items and each item goes into a category. Each category has it's own set of attributes which the item fulfills.

So I would have

```
Items
itemId
name
catId


ItemAttribute
itemId
AttId
Value


Category
CatId
Name

Attribute
AttId
CatId
Name
```

Its a bit simplistic but you get the idea.
Sometimes you have to step one step out to see the pattern and your database schema.

Comment: I appreciate the opinions. I'm rewriting most of the schema to categorize the data (will still keep some of the json for pratical reason).

Comment: Sure, I think there are times when json is a necessary evil. I remember once making some dynamic form thing and you could make a chart and I needed to have the settings somewhere and json seemed the best at the time. But I would always say that where possible see the pattern and it will help you in the long run